# add angular directive with template dynamicly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello people from Stackoverflow,

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive("newcard", function() {
   return{
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: '*templateUrl*',
      link : function ($scope) {
         scope.cardId = numberOfCards;
      }
   };
})
```

But when i add this dynamicly with:

```
$('.tree-cards').append('<newcard></newcard>');
```

All it adds is just an empty tag.
Is there a way to replace that with the content of the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, i tried to use $compile but was afraid it didn't work. turned out that i had to inject the dependancy for compile on the right place.

In each case, this works for me:

```
var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('.tree-cards'));
var appendHtml = $compile('<newcard></newcard>')($scope);
divElement.append(appendHtml);
```